# Multifold integration with Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This question may seem silly but I cannot find a way to solve it by myself. I need to do some multifold integrations (at least four fold) whose range is infinite with Matlab, and I did not found any suitable functions.

For example, how should I do the following integral:

Integrate[f(x,y,z,w),{x,-\infty,\infty},{y,-\infty,\infty},{z,-\infty,\infty},{w,-\infty,\infty}]

where the function f may be defined as

f=1/(x-y)*1/(z-w)*exp(-0.25*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2))

In Matlab, sometimes one needs to add a dot behind the arguments so the function can be executed, which I am very confused about.

I appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: If you mean _symbolic_ integration, please add the "symbolic-math" tag to your answer

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean **symbolic** integration. For that

1. Define your [symbolic variables](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html).
2. Define your function of those symbolic variables.
3. Apply [`int`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) repeatedly to integrate with respect to each variable. This assumes the function satisfies the hypotheses of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) (which it does for your example function).

So:

```
>> syms x y z w                           %// step 1
>> f = exp(-x^2-y^2-z^2-w^2)              %// step 2
f =
exp(- w^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)
>> F = f
F =
exp(- w^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)
>> F = int(F,x,-inf,inf)                  %// step 3: x
F =
pi^(1/2)*exp(-w^2)*exp(-y^2)*exp(-z^2)
>> F = int(F,y,-inf,inf)                  %// step 3: y
F =
pi*exp(- w^2 - z^2)
>> F = int(F,z,-inf,inf)                  %// step 3: z
F =
pi^(3/2)*exp(-w^2)
>> F = int(F,w,-inf,inf)                  %// step 3: w
F =
pi^2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes eventually I will do symbolic calculations. However, the integrand is a function that I define by myself. For these functions, it seems sometimes a dot behind the argument is needed to run the integral, but I am very bad at that. I just edited the question to include this, can you have a look? I appreciate if you are willing to help.

Comment: Do you mean [element-wise multiplication](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)?

Comment: Perhaps... The kind of things that I need to do is like to first integrate over w and z and get a result as a function of x and y, it is okay if an analytic expression cannot be obtained. Then I need to multiply the resulting function of x and y with another function of x and y, and do the integral of their product

Comment: So you want parametric integration. But's that what `int` does. See my example. I integrate with respect to `x` and then with respect to `y`. The result of that is a function of `w` and `z`, namely `pi*exp(-w^2-z^2)`. You can assign that result to a symbolic variable (`F` in my example), multiply it by some other function, and then keep integrating with respect to other variables